# Docusaurus: how to add SEO meta tags

Tags: docusaurus

I need to add SEO meta tags (e.g `<link rel="canonical" href="bla-bla" />`) to the pages which are generated by Docusaurus. As I understand I can use "@docusaurus/Head" component (https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/docusaurus-core), but I'm not sure where to use it: I have a project that was created for v1, the structure of the project looks like this:

```
|-docs
|---someFileForDoc1.md
|---someFileForDoc2.md
|-website
|---siteConfig.js
```

Where should I use this component?

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from '@docusaurus/Head';
const MySEO = () => (
  <>
    <Head>
      <meta property="og:description" content="My custom description" />
      <meta charSet="utf-8" />
      <title>My Title</title>
      <link rel="canonical" href="bla-bla" />
    </Head>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that won't work because you are using V2 APIs in a V1 website. I don't think this is possible in V1.